# conic arc function

Tags: conic-sections, bezier-curve, spline

I would like to have a function $f(x,\alpha)$ looking like this:

[image: each line correspond to a different value of $\alpha$]

- The lower the line, the bigger $\alpha$ is
- The straight line in the middle correspond to $\alpha=0$
- The line forming the upper left corner correspond to $\alpha=-\infty$
- The line forming the lower right corner correspond to $\alpha=\infty$

At the moment, I use the function $f(x) = x^{(e^\alpha)}$, but it's not good. I would like my function to have a symmetry axis corresponding to the dotted line in the picture above. I think it should be a conic

I don't really know how to start to developp the equations. Could you help me find $f(x,\alpha)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the superellipse. For the curves you want, this can be written as

$$
y=(1-(1-x)^{1/p})^p,\quad x\in[0,1]
$$

I believe my $p$ is your $\alpha$, but check. My curves look as shown below,

[image: Superellipse variation]

Comment: That is kinda what I want, but lines below converge more rapidly to the corner than lines above. I believe your p is composed of exponential values starting from zero.

Comment: anyway, it will be easy to make the graph totally symmetric with a simple condition. A big thank you for this answer !!!

Comment: The lines are not evenly spaced because they are logarithmic in order to cover a range of vales from.02 to 100.